# Neo4j IllegalStateException: relationship X has been deleted (linked list query)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a linked list pattern like this:

```
(list) -[:next]-> (a) -[:next]-> (b) -[next...]-> (z)
```

i.e. Where every element in the list is guaranteed to have an incoming (preceding) `next` relationship, but the last one in the list will have no outgoing (following) one...

I have this query for atomically removing one or more nodes from such lists:

```
START nodeToRemove = node({ids})
MATCH nodeBefore -[relBefore:next]-> nodeToRemove
DELETE relBefore

WITH nodeToRemove, nodeBefore
MATCH nodeToRemove -[relAfter:next]-> nodeAfter
CREATE nodeBefore -[relNew:next]-> nodeAfter
SET relNew = relAfter

WITH relAfter
DELETE relAfter
```

This is a pre-2.0 style query, but the syntax works with Neo4j 2.0 too. It says, for each input node:

1. Delete the incoming (i.e. preceding) `next` relationship.
2. Then look for an outgoing (i.e. following) `next` relationship.
3. If there is one, "rewire" it to connect the `(before)` node to the `(after)` one.

   (Since relationship connections are immutable in Neo4j, this last step is achieved by creating a new relationship with the same props as the old one, then deleting the old one.)

(And this query is written in this way specifically because the last node in the list won't have an outgoing `next` relationship, but always has an incoming one.)

This used to work fine with Neo4j 1.8, but it fails now in Neo4j 1.9 if I pass in adjacent nodes. The error is this:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Relationship <id> has been deleted
```

Which implies that the entire query isn't "processed" before relationships get deleted. This used to work in Neo4j 1.8 though, I swear. =)

How can I fix this? Here's a live console to play with this for yourself:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/jhk8cc

Paste in the query above, and just replace `{ids}` with `1, 2`. Individual nodes like `1` and `2` work. (Thanks @cybersam for the initial tip!)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that, as of 1.9, the SET operation is is being performed *after* the 'DELETE relAfter' operation.

How about splitting things up a bit more:

```
START nodeToRemove = node({id})
MATCH nodeBefore -[relBefore:next]-> nodeToRemove
DELETE relBefore

WITH nodeToRemove, nodeBefore
MATCH nodeToRemove -[relAfter:next]-> nodeAfter
CREATE nodeBefore -[relNew:next]-> nodeAfter
SET relNew = relAfter

WITH relAfter
DELETE relAfter
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, but I do need the `SET` to copy over all the relationship props. Is there another way to achieve that?

Comment: Update: separating the `SET` and `DELETE` with a `WITH` does the trick! Thanks Sam!

Comment: If you update your answer I'm happy to mark it correct. Your tip that the `SET` executes after the `DELETE` gave me the idea to try `WITH`. =)

Comment: Actually, this still doesn't work with multiple IDs, which was what I was originally debugging... =/ Would it be unkosher of me to un-mark this as the answer and edit the question?

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows when this is failing?

Comment: Yep, the bottom of my question has a console link and examples: `1, 2` and `2, 3` will both fail, while `1, 3` and individual nodes all work.

Comment: I may have a solution, but am still working on it. However, I think what you were doing originally, even in 1.8, was not quite right. (1) The 'SET relNew = relAfter' statement only retains the props of the relationship AFTER a removed node. The props of the relationship BEFORE that node are thrown away. Is this really what you want? (2) If multiple adjacent nodes are removed, then at the end of the query only the relAfter props for the relationship following ONE of those nodes is retained. Again, is this what you really want?

Comment: Thanks Sam. (1) A relationship's properties don't change if a node gets deleted. What do you mean? (2) Yes, if multiple adjacent nodes are removed, the node preceding the first should now be connected to the node following the last. Standard linked list deletion.

Comment: When I originally questioned whether you needed the SET statement, you said you needed to "copy over all the relationship props". My most recent comment is saying that your original query would have dropped a lot of relationship props. I believe that is a bug in your original approach, even in 1.8.

Comment: I'm not sure... If I have (a) -[1]-> (b) -[2]-> (c), and I remove (b), I want (a) -[2]-> (c). I believe my query does that... If multiple adjacent nodes are getting deleted, the intent of my query is that each node should be deleted one by one. If that happens, the result should be correct.

Comment: Even assuming everything worked properly, if you have (a) -[1]-> (b) -[2]-> (c) -[3]-> (d), and you remove (b) and (c), in that order: you will end up with (a) -[3]-> (d), and [2] will be dropped. In the same scenario, if you remove (c) before (b), you *might*, depending on the query, end up with (a) -[2]-> (d), and [3] will be dropped. Are you sure you want to allow any relationship properties to be dropped, and is it OK for the results to depend on the order in with nodes are removed?

Comment: That shouldn't happen — the query is saying if you remove a node, remove its preceding (incoming) relationship. You can think of it as each node owns / is attached to that relationship. So if you remove b and c, in either order, the result should be (a) -[3]-> (d).